# Woocommerce multisite network => get attribute terms of products from other blog id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, multisite

We have a multisite Worpdress Installation with two woocommerce shops.

In blog_id 2 we need to get some products with their attribute values (pa_testattr) from blog_id 1.
It does work well, we get the desired products, product names & image do show up so far.
But we do not get the attribute values/terms from pa_testattr assigend to these products to show up.

Here is the code we have:

```
switch_to_blog(1); 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'category' =>  'my_cat',
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'order'  => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10 
);

foreach( wc_get_products($args) as $product ){
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    // echo  $product_id.'<br>';

// THIS DOES NOT WORK 
foreach( wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'pa_testattr' ) as $attribute_value ){
   echo $attribute_value . '<br>';
}
// THIS DOES NOT WORK 


// THIS DOES ALSO NOT WORK  (Output empty: string(0) "")
$myattr = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_testattr' );
var_dump($myattr);
// THIS DOES ALSO NOT WORK  (Output empty: string(0) "")

echo '<p>' . $product->get_name() . '</p>';
echo $product->get_image();


}


restore_current_blog();
```

Where is the mistake? Cant we acces the attributes from another blog ID?

Comment: It does work now. I think had problems with duplicate term slugs (but they were still assigned to different taxonomies, ... hum?)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue were even after I switch blogs the taxonomy from, to use your example, blog #1 isn't available in blog #2. My solution was to temporarily trick WordPress into thinking the taxonomy exists which in tern will allow you to access the terms.

```
switch_to_blog(1);

// get the global taxonomies object...
global $wp_taxonomies;

// trick Wordpress into thinking 'pa_testattr' is a value taxonomy on blogs other than #1
// so we don't get the 'Invalid Taxonomy' error
if (!array_key_exists('pa_testattr', $wp_taxonomies)) {
  register_taxonomy(
    'pa_testattr',
    array(
      'product',
    ),
    array(
      'hierarchical' => true,
    )
  );
  $added_temp_taxonomy = true;
} else {
  $added_temp_taxonomy = false;
}

// get terms, for example
$tags = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy' => 'pa_testattr',
  'hide_empty' => true,
) );

// do what you need to do with them...

// remove the taxonomy if it was added temporarily 
if ($added_temp_taxonomy) {
  unregister_taxonomy('pa_testattr');
}

restore_current_blog();
```